# Python Method for Text Input from Project Euler

Tags: python, programming-challenge, io

### Method

Frequently input for problems is given as a 1D or 2D array in a text file.

Have knocked out a method to do so, but believe something shorter, clearer and cheaper can be written:

```
def read_array_from_txt(path, dim, typ, sep):
    '''
    @time: O(n)
    @space: O(n)
    '''
    txt_file_object = open(path,"r")
    text = txt_file_object.readlines()
    text = text[0]
    if dim == 1:
        if typ == "int":
            text = [int(num) for num in text.split(sep)]
        elif typ == "str":
            text = [let for let in text.split(sep)]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown type.")
    elif dim == 2:
        if typ == "int":
            text = [[int(num) for num in line.split(sep)] for line in text]
        if typ == "str":
            text = [[let for let in line.split(sep)] for line in text]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown type.")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown dimension.")
    txt_file_object.close()
    return text
```

### An Example:

Input: encrypted_message.txt

```
36,22,80,0,0,4,23,25,19,17,88,4,4,19
```

Output:

```
>>> read_array_from_txt("./encrypted_message.txt", 1, "int", ",")
[36,22,80,0,0,4,23,25,19,17,88,4,4,19]
```

### Some Other Possible Inputs:

```
1   37  79  164 155 32  87  39  113 15  18  78  175 140 200 4   160 97  191 100 91  20  69  198 196 
2   123 134 10  141 13  12  43  47  3   177 101 179 77  182 117 116 36  103 51  154 162 128 30  
3   48  123 134 109 41  17  159 49  136 16  130 141 29  176 2   190 66  153 157 70  114 65  173 104 194 54
```

```
are,in,hello,hi,ok,yes,no,is
```

Comment: Could you include an example how you'd use this?

Comment: Have you tested this? It seems to me to have at least one obvious bug.

Comment: Tested and have used this on several problems, but could have missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let's make use of the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) statement so that the file is closed automatically:

```py
with open(path, 'r') as txt_file_object:
    text = txt_file_object.readlines()
```

With this, you don't have to call `close()` anymore, as the file will close automatically when you exit the `with` scope.

---

`text = text[0]`

You are only reading the first line of text. Is this really what you want to do?

---

You are using the variable `text` for two different things: for the input lines and for the output values. This is not very intuitive; in fact, the result can be a list of integers, so why would it be called `text`? Maybe `result` would be a better name for it.

BUT since now you don't have to close at the end of the function, you can return the result directly instead of saving it in a variable:

```py
return [int(num) for num in text.split(sep)]
```

Returning will exit the `with` scope, so again the file will be closed automatically.

---

```py
[let for let in text.split(sep)]
```

This selects all objects inside `text.split(sep)`, so we can return the splitted list directly:

```py
text.split(sep)
```

Similarly, there's a different way of applying a function to every item in a list, which is using `map`. Maybe the list comprehension feels more natural, so you can keep that if you want; still I'll show you just so you know:

```py
# Creates a list by calling 'int' to every item in the list
list(map(int, text.split(sep))
```

---

You are repating a lot of code; you have four different results, but they are very similar, so let's try to provide a more generic way.

My concern here is handling the two possible dimensions. You are parsing the text in the same way (depending if it's int or str), but when it's two dimensions you do it for every line. So we could use Python's [**lambdas**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) to decide first what type of parsing (int or str) we are doing, and then just apply it once or multiple times.

The lambda can take parameters; the only parameter we need in our case is the input text. We can't just use `text` directly because sometimes we want to parse the full text, but sometimes only the line:

```py
if typ == "int":
    parse_function = lambda t: list(map(int, t.split(sep)))
elif typ == "str":
    parse_function = lambda t: list(t.split(sep))
else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown type.")
```

Now `parse_function` can be used like any other function, taking the text as input. So we can use it when deciding the dimension:

```py
if dim == 1:
    return parse_function(text)
elif dim == 2:
    return [parse_function(line) for line in text]
else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown dimension.")
```

---

You do well in throwing exceptions for invalid input, but how is the user meant to know what possible values can be used for `typ` and `dim`? You could add that to the docstring. You should also say what the function does in the docstring.

### Updated code

```py
def read_array_from_txt(path, dim, typ, sep):
    '''
    Processes a text file as a 1D or 2D array.
    :param path: Path to the input file.
    :param dim: How many dimensions (1 or 2) the array has.
    :param typ: Whether the elements are read as 'int' or 'str'
    :param sep: The text that is used to separate between elements.
    @time: O(n)
    @space: O(n)
    '''
    with open(path,"r") as txt_file_object:
        text = txt_file_object.readlines()

        if typ == "int":
            parse_function = lambda t: list(map(int, t.split(sep)))
        elif typ == "str":
            parse_function = lambda t: list(t.split(sep))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown type.")

        if dim == 1:
            return parse_function(text)
        elif dim == 2:
            return [parse_function(line) for line in text]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown dimension.")
```

Comment: Like the comment on explaining inputs in doscstring; and removal of redundancy via lambdas. Disinclined to use with; explicitly closing seems clearer.

Comment: `str.split` already returns a list, so `list(text.split(sep))` is redundant.

@A.L.Verminburger: The `with` scope gives you more than just calling `close`. It guarantees that the file will be closed (barring the computer instantaneously dying). Even in the event of an exception (which would prevent your `close` from running. It is a well-known and often used Python idiom, which I would recommend getting used to.

Comment: True, I assumed it would return a generator. I will edit the answer now, thanks.

Comment: You didn't remove `list(...)` from all the cases of `list(text.split(sep))`.  You missed this one: `parse_function = lambda t: list(t.split(sep))`

Comment: You'll want `return parse_function(text[0])` on the `dim == 1` case, because `text` is a list, not a string.